# Why is the node prompt in spacemacs bizarre?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs, spacemacs

When from within spacemacs, I run the `shell` command, then run `node` to get the REPL I see the usual node prompt of

```
>
```

looking like this craziness

```
^[[1G^[[0J> ^[[3G
```

Everything actually works fine beyond that and - while I'm interested in knowing how to fix this - even more I'm interested in understanding **why** this happens. It certainly seems like a bizarre thing that I don't really get (btw when I start the powershell OSX alpha I get similar odd displays)

Comment: It's sending terminal control escape sequences, which `spacemacs` doesn't understand because it's not a terminal emulator.

Comment: Emacs *does* contain a number of terminal emulators, but `shell` isn't one of them.  Try `M-x ansi-term` instead.  IIRC there is a `comint` module you can push in order to get something similar in `shell`, too.

Comment: Interesting. @tripleee what *is* shell then if its not a terminal emulator?

Comment: There is no emulation of anything out of the box, though you could of course argue that it emulates a dumb teletype from circa 1963, minus the form feed and overstrike features.